# git status --ignored in homestead 5.2 not showing all files

Tags: git, homestead

I've been running all my terminal commands via `vagrant ssh` to maintain consistency with my php version.

Here's the rub. I did some rejiggering in my Laravel 5.4 project

`/project
  /laravel-stuff
  /public_html`

and when I run `git status --ignored` through the Vagrant shell I only get the file in the top-level directory for the project.

When I run `git status --ignored` from my PHPStorm terminal or through my mac terminal I see all the ignored files as expected.

Any thoughts?